# Limitations of the Global Picklist?

Tags: global-picklist

What all are the limitations of the global picklist ? I dont see any proper documentation of the salesforce and some web post are vague.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a Global Picklist Value Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_creating_global_picklists.htm&language=en_US&type=0) has this to say:

> A global picklist is a restricted picklist by nature. Only a Salesforce admin can add to or modify its values. Users can’t add unapproved values, even through the API.
>
> Note: You can have up to 500 picklist global value sets in an org. Each global value set, or restricted picklist, can contain a mix of 1,000 active and inactive values. Unrestricted picklists can have up to 1,000 active values. There’s no limit on the number of custom picklists that use global picklist value sets.

So, the general limits are 500 picklists per org, 1,000 values per list, and unapproved values are not allowed.